# PHP SpreadSheet - Convert col+row to cell

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet

I'm trying with PHP Spreadsheet and I would like to convert from col+row to range. Example: col -> 1 and row -> 1 = "A1"

Example:

```
$worksheet2->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue());
```

to:

```
$worksheet2->getCellValue(¿?);
```

How to convert from $col and $row variable to range(Ex: "A1")?

Thanks!

Comment: No. I have edited my post with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
function colLetter($c, $offset=null){
   // https://icesquare.com/wordpress/example-code-to-convert-a-number-to-excel- 
   //column-letter/
   //0 -> A
   //25 -> Z
   //26 -> AA
   //27 -> AB
   //799 -> ADT

    if ( is_null($offset) ) { //converts position 0 to 2 etc etc.
        $offset = 0;
    }
    $offset += 1;  //the solution converts 1 -> A, hence we need to add 1 if we want to start with zero

    $c = (int)$c;
    if ($c < 0) {
        return '';
    } else {
        $c += $offset;
    }
    $letter = '';             
    while($c != 0){
       $p = ($c - 1) % 26;
       $c = (int)(($c - $p) / 26);
       $letter = chr(65 + $p) . $letter;
    }    
    return $letter;        
}
```

This would write something into column $key+3 which is column D (if $key is 0):

```
$xC = colLetter( (int)$key, 3 );        
$ws->setCellValue( $xC . '2', $date )
   ->setCellValue( $xC . '444', $datedmy );
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved straightforward with PHP SpreadSheet:

```
$worksheet2->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getCoordinate();
```

Example:

```
echo $worksheet2->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, 2)->getCoordinate();
```

returns `C2`